# Zend Framework : Apc Cache Backend unintendedly cleared

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, apc

I'm using Apc backend cache in Zend Framework. It works fine when I do GET requests, my objects are stored in cache and I'm able to retrieve them.

The problem is, when I do a POST request (it seems to be the trigger), the apc cache is empty. Is it a Zend issue, or due to APC configuration? I searched into the documentation, but I saw nothing about the request type (GET or POST).

Do you have any idea why my cache is empty?

Thanks

EDIT : some code

**In controller:**

```
$cacheId = 'cache_key';
$cache = Cache_CacheHandler::getClassCache($cacheId);
if (($form = $cache->load($cacheId)) === false) { // cache missed
    ...
```

**In Bootstrap:**

/**
 * Initialisation du cache Zend
 */
protected function _initZendCache()
{
    //Class Cache : stocke les objets
    $classCache = Zend_Cache::factory(
        'Class', //Frontend
        'Apc', //Backend
        array('cached_entity' => 'MY_MODEL_NAME')
    );

```
Zend_Registry::set('classCache', $classCache);
```

}

Comment: +1: this is interesting, even though I never found the problem myself... Can you show us some code where the problem happens?

Comment: I don't get the connection between caching and requests? How are they connected in your app, what do you cache at what point of the app flow and what are you getting back at what point? Are you maybe abusing the cache?